# CSS Animations skip in Firefox when animated element is out of viewport

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Try using this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4kzu2jc/14/) in Chrome and in Firefox.
Here's the code:

(HTML)

```
<div class="slide-down">
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
</div>
```

(CSS)

```
.slide-down {
  font-size: 3em;
  -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-name: slideDown;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideDown;
}
@-moz-keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    -moz-transform:translateY(-300px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform:translateY(0px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-300px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

My issue is that it works in Chrome but only works in Firefox when the starting coordinates (at the "0%" point of the animation) of the animated div are within the viewport. Otherwise, it can completely skip the animation. Try changing the translateY() parameter to something more conservative, like -50px, and it will work.
Is there a workaround for this? It would be nice to be able to bring something in from outside the screen without having to write a script to figure out what its initial y-coordinate should be.

Comment: You forgot the most important CSS property of all: the not prefixed one, which you should place after the vendor prefixed ones. The final, W3C compliant property might have a slightly different implementation than browser specific ones. To get the same experience across all browsers, it is paramount that you add the prefixless version, and the prefixed ones only if you need support for older browsers.

Comment: @BramVanroy can you clarify what you mean, by adding an updated version of the JSFiddle or code that you've verified produces the expected result in Firefox? I believe I did exactly what you described here: https://jsfiddle.net/h4kzu2jc/30/. But it's still not working properly in Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider animating the margin instead:

```css
.slide-down {
  font-size: 3em;
  animation:slideDown 3s forwards;
}
@keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    margin-top:-300px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-down">
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is an elegant solution that works in both Chrome and Firefox. I should refactor my real code to incorporate the shorthand you use. The only nitpicky thing I have to say is that technically it's best to include the prefixes if Bram is right (though I probably don't have a good reason for supporting very old browsers anyway...)